# how to fetch single attribute from redis cache spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

how to fetch a single attribute from Redis cache spring boot?

I want a response like this one

```
       {

        "answer": "FHFHFHFHFH" 
       }
```

but getting this one Please do let me know what should I do?

```
          {

               "questionId":58,
              "answer":"FHFHFHFHFH"
          }
```

this is the response I am getting from the above API

below this code which I am using

Controller :->>>

```
          @GetMapping("/getAnswerStudentExam/{questionId}")
          @ResponseBody
         public ResponseEntity getAnswerStudentExam(@PathVariable Long 
          questionId){
            System.out.println("getAnswerStudentExam  " +questionId);
            QuentionCacheEntity item = answerCache.getAnswerStudent(questionId);
         System.out.println("answerCache.getAnswerStudent(questionId); " +questionId);
            return new ResponseEntity(item, HttpStatus.OK);
         }
```

this API call this method

```
         @Cacheable(value = "ansCache", key = "#questionId")
         public QuentionCacheEntity getAnswerStudent(Long questionId) {

        QuentionCacheEntity answer = null;
            try {

            answer = ansQuestionRepo.getAnswerFromRedis(questionId);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

this method will call this

```
          public QuentionCacheEntity getAnswerFromRedis(Long questionId){
             return  (QuentionCacheEntity) hashOperations.get(KEY,questionId);
         }
```

Below is model

code-->>>

```
          import java.io.Serializable;
          import javax.persistence.Id;
          import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
         import lombok.Data;
       import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
        @Data
        @NoArgsConstructor
       @AllArgsConstructor
       public class QuentionCacheEntity implements Serializable {
      @Id
        private Long questionId;

        private String answer;

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add @JsonIgnore to the `questionId` field in QuentionCacheEntity (should that be QuestionCacheEntity?) so that when Jackson serializes the object in the ReST controller it knows to ignore that field.

Comment: Big Thank You sir Its working Very thank you